# GDB: Debug two instances of the same application simultaneous

Tags: c++, gdb

I am trying to debug two instances of the same application. Therefore I setup as followed:

```
(gdb) set target-async on
(gdb) set non-stop on
(gdb) attach pid1
(gdb) set scheduler-locking off
(gdb) add-inferior
(gdb) inferior 2
(gdb) attach pid2
(gdb) set scheduler-locking off
(gdb) b hello-world.cpp:8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x557a557761fd: ../hello-world.cpp:8. (2 locations)
(gdb) continue
```

The Problem I have is that only the currently selected inferior is continued. Is there a way to let all inferiors continue with one command?

Solution:

It works if the following sequnce is used:

```
(gdb) attach pid1
(gdb) add-inferior
(gdb) inferior 2
(gdb) attach pid2
(gdb) set schedule-multiple on
(gdb) b hello-world.cpp:8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x557a557761fd: ../hello-world.cpp:8. (2 locations)
(gdb) continue
```

Thanks to Klaus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue all attached processes you have to set the scheduler mode in gdb.

> set scheduler-locking off

A continue now let all threads continue.

For a detailed description of scheduler mode take a look [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/All_002dStop-Mode.html)

As you ask in the comments what the complete procedure was:

```
(gdb) attach <pid 1>
(gdb) add-inferior
(gdb) inferior 2
(gdb) attach <pid 2>
(gdb) set scheduler-locking off
(gdb) b myprog.cpp:55
```

Comment: I tried with `set scheduler-locking off` and also `set schedule-multiple` but the behavior is still the same. Any additional suggestion?

Comment: @Toroid On which OS you are running? I tried it and it worked as expected and described. I only attach 2 inferiors, set the breakpoint, set scheduler mode and continued. Both attached tasks have continued until both are running in next breakpoint.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu (WSL) on Windows 10

Comment: @Toroid: All the scheduler settings are dependent on the underlying OS. Maybe Windows did not support the necessary functionality or we have simply a bug. It might help if you ask on:  gdb@sourceware.org for support. There is hopefully more attention to os dependent problems. As said, it works from scratch on native linux.

Comment: I tried in a Linux VM and it also didn't work. Did you use the same procedure of comments as given in the initial question?

Comment: As I already wrote in my comment, only that list of comands, no settings you have used!" I only attach 2 inferiors, set the breakpoint, set scheduler mode and continued. "

Comment: Ok it works if I use the command set `schedule-multiple on`

Comment: @Toroid: So you should accept the answer hwich makes it easier to other users to seee that the solution works....and upvote,  thats how we pay for other people effort. Upvote is the way to say thanks...